# Why do some fonts not seem to work as a default/global font in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts

I've been trying to make Firefox use Wingdings as the default font for all text on macOS (please do not ask why). Following [this guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use#w_changing-font), I went to the Fonts & Colors section and changed all the fonts to Wingdings. However, Firefox does not seem to like this, and instead uses some Arial-like font for all pages.

Doing the exact same thing, but using another font, such as Comic Sans, does work however.

Why does Comic Sans work as a global font, but not Wingdings? And how can I force Firefox to use Wingdings?

Further experimenting, it seems like some Wingdings-like fonts do not work, like Webdings or Wingdings 2 and 3. Most other fonts seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You say "don't ask" ...but setting a font with only 100 or so specific glyphs in it to be default would mean only those 100 glyphs would ever show.

They wouldn't *automagically* replace 'real' letters… instead when any non-wingdings glyph was called, the system would have to try find **something** to replace that non-existant glyph with, or else all you'd see would be ⌷⌷⌷⌷⌷ ⌷⌷⌷ ⌷⌷⌷⌷ ⌷⌷⌷⌷⌷⌷. It would seem your system has rather sensibly chosen Arial, a fairly comprehensive font set, rather than than a screen-full of boxes.

Using Comic Sans will give you closer to what you asked, for regular 'letters' [whatever you think of Comic Sans, I shan't comment;) because it also contains at least the regular glyph set of standard letters.

---

Comment: But a lot of characters replaced by Arial are bound to glyphs in Wingdings. Like C, for example, is a thumbs-up glyph, but it still shows up in Arial. Shouldn't it show the Wingding-glyph?